# EWS Managed API - resource, enabled, shared

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I need to get the properties of email address(es). I have been reading and studying documentation at Microsoft and other places and I cannot get answers to my problem with getting some properties of email addresses.

Using: Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data

I am getting mailbox from GAL by the means of

```
ResolveName(
    ambiguousName,
    ResolveNameSearchLocation.DirectoryOnly,
    true,
    view.PropertySet);
```

All is ok - I got list emails which consists of Mailbox and Public Groups Types ....

**Questions and problems:**

1. How can I check that an email address - mailbox is enabled? I mean being used and not suspended by administrator etc ...
2. How can I distinguish regular person email box from resource box? I found some answers to that on Stackoverflow which ended with suggestion to mark the resources, but I'd like to avoid it. Is there a property or anything that can distinguish person's mailbox from e.g. Car mailbox? I looked in debug mode and compared the Mailbox props and Contact props but so far with no luck.
3. How can I check if an address is shared resource and if others got access to it?

Answer (score 0):

> Using: Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data

EWS is a Mailbox Access API not an administration API most of the questions your asking will only be solved fully by using the Exchange Management Shell cmdlets

1. No use Get-Mailbox will tell you this
2. No you need Get-Mailbox for that
3. You can check the folder level permission and Delegate Access in EWS eg https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/delegate-access-and-ews-in-exchange however Mailbox level permissions will need Get-MailboxPermission